# How to get specific field from DB query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to query my DB for only the `dateFormatted` field, sorted by the `timestamp` field, but the query returns all of the fields not just `dateFormatted`:

```
    const allUsersFiles = await db.FileMetadata.find({
        username: username
    }).select('dateFormatted').sort({
        timestamp: 'desc'
    });
```

mongoose `5.10.11`
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll have to do something like this,

```
await db.FileMetadata.find({
     username: username
}).select({'dateFormatted':1}).sort({timestamp: 'desc'});
```

Also, _id will be returned by default. If you want to skip the keys, assign them value 0.